# Postfix & Amavis - Use UNIX Soket for Communication

Tags: postfix, smtp, spam, socket, amavis

I currently using a complex mailserver setup using **Postfix, Dovecot, Amavis and Spamassassin**.

Everything works fine but I want to improve the Postfix-Amavis-Communication. At the moment, postfix will send all mails to `localhost:10024` which is the amavis service. After all checks a modified version is sent back to `localhost:10025` which is a postfix service for recieving amavis mails.

My idea: **UNIX SOCKETS** *(Because of security reasons; not important why)*

So I configured amavis to spawn an unix socket in `/run/amavis/amavis.socket`.

And I changed this:

```
amavis-forward:[127.0.0.1]:10024` to `amavis-forward:unix:/run/amavis/amavis.sock
```

But then I get this error:

```
Jan  5 13:55:23 server postfix/smtp[1447]: fatal: unknown service: /run/amavis/amavis.sock/tcp
Jan  5 13:55:24 server postfix/qmgr[1254]: warning: private/amavis-forward socket: malformed response
Jan  5 13:55:24 server postfix/qmgr[1254]: warning: transport amavis-forward failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
```

So the mail status is set to `status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)`.

master.cf:

```
 ...
 # Amavis
 amavis-forward   unix    -       -       -       -       2       smtp
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20
 ...
```

Over :10024 anything works fine. How can I solve it?

Comment: 1. Did you restart postfix? 2. often postfix likes its sockets in `/var/spool/amavis` 3. Have you updated your `master.cf`?

Comment: Yes, I added amavis-forward and restarted anything including the whole root server. If I use inet port it works fine... I only change th content_filter rule...

Comment: Using var/spool: `postfix/smtp[1663]: fatal: unknown service: /var/spool/amavis/amavis.sock/tcp`

Comment: You need to change the line in `master.cf` also!

Comment: What? Posted master.cf part...

Comment: `unix   The service listens on a UNIX-domain socket and is acces-
                     sible for local clients only.

                     The service name is a pathname relative  to  the  Postfix
                     queue    directory    (pathname   controlled   with   the
                     queue_directory configuration parameter in main.cf).`

Comment: Please read the second sentence with special care :)

Comment: @NickW If you think that will solve the problem, you should post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Does not work... Postfix took "../amavis/amavis.sock" and use it as "/var/spool/amavis/amavis.sock" but I get the same error message. I do not undestand why postfix adds "/tcp" to the socket...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this is half answer because I can use socket when postfix -> amavis but I can't use it when amavis -> postfix. See the explanation in end of this answer.*

To use socket, you should use LMTP instead of SMTP to deliver email from postfix to amavis.

As NickW said above, you need to put the amavis socket inside the Postfix queue directory. **In this answer I assume that postfix queue directory is** `/var/spool/postfix/`.

Create directory to hold amavis socket

```
mkdir /var/spool/postfix/amavis/
chmod 750 /var/spool/postfix/amavis/
chown amavis:amavis /var/spool/postfix/amavis/
```

Add postfix user in amavis group

```
usermod -G amavis postfix
```

Configuration in `amavisd.conf`

```
# for socket, it should reside in /var/spool/postfix
$unix_socketname = "/var/spool/postfix/amavis/amavisd.sock";

# set permission so amavis group can access this socket
$unix_socket_mode = 0660;

# Replace $interface_policy{'SOCK'} = 'AM.PDP';

$interface_policy{'SOCK'} = 'mysock';
$policy_bank{'mysock'} = {
   protocol => 'LMTP',
   auth_required_release => 0, # don't require secret-id for release
};
```

Postfix main.cf

```
content_filter = amavis-forward:unix:amavis/amavisd.sock
```

Postfix master.cf

```
# Amavis
amavis-forward   unix    -       -       -       -       2       lmtp
    -o lmtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o lmtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20
```

The result

```
amais postfix/smtpd[13393]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
amais postfix/smtpd[13393]: 4E0B82340F: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
amais postfix/cleanup[13359]: 4E0B82340F: message-id=<20150106070245.4E0B82340F@example.net>
amais postfix/qmgr[13352]: 4E0B82340F: from=<root@example.net>, size=344, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
amais postfix/smtpd[13363]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
amais postfix/smtpd[13363]: 6081E2340B: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
amais postfix/cleanup[13359]: 6081E2340B: message-id=<20150106070245.4E0B82340F@example.net>
amais postfix/qmgr[13352]: 6081E2340B: from=<root@example.net>, size=688, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
amais postfix/smtpd[13363]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
amais postfix/local[13365]: 6081E2340B: to=<root@example.net>, orig_to=<koala@example.net>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
amais postfix/qmgr[13352]: 6081E2340B: removed
amais amavis[13113]: (13113-03) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, mysock <root@example.net> -> <koala@example.net>, Message-ID: <20150106070245.4E0B82340F@example.net>, mail_id: MLZDzoda7siu, Hits: -, size: 344, queued_as: 6081E2340B, 90 ms
amais postfix/lmtp[13361]: 4E0B82340F: to=<koala@example.net>, relay=example.net[amavis/amavisd.sock], delay=0.11, delays=0.01/0/0.01/0.09, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6081E2340B)
amais postfix/qmgr[13352]: 4E0B82340F: removed
```

---

For amavis -> postfix transport, it controlled by parameter `forward_method`. I don't familiar with this configuration except with smtp. In the [example in this page](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/amavisd/amavisd-114/amavisd/amavisd-new-2.4.4/amavisd.conf-sample), apparently protocol supported by this parameter is pipe, smtp, and bsmtp. Also, based on [postfix architecture](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html), postfix only accept email either from smtpd, qmqmd, or sendmail.

Comment: Read my second answer...

Answer (score 2):

*This is the solution for a communication of amavis to postfix over unix socket. It is the second half of masegaloeh's answer.*

First, you have to modify the `/var/spool/postfix/amavis` directory:

```
chmod 770 /var/spool/postfix/amavis
chown amavis:postfix /var/spool/postfix/amavis
```

The idea behind that: Postfix will create a unix socket smtpd service in this directory. The problem is that you have define that in the master.cf as `../amavis/amavis-accept - - - 2 smtpd` but then postfix will search the pid file in `pid/unix...amavis/amavis-accept` which does not work.
So we have to use a workaround:

Create a link to the `amavis` directory:

```
cd /var/spool/postfix/public
ln -s ../amavis amavis
```

After that the pid file directory has to be prepared:

```
cd /var/spool/postfix/pid
mkdir unix.amavis
chown root:root unix.amavis
chmod 700 unix.amavis
```

Now we have to configure the smtpd service to accept the mail (master.cf):

```
amavis/amavis-accept     unix    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
    -o cleanup_service_name=amaviscleanup
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

Now configure amavis in amavisd.conf or the config file of your os:

```
$forward_method = 'smtp:/var/spool/postfix/amavis/amavis-accept';
```

---

### HOW IT WORKS

The mail is forwarded to amavis which you can see in the first half of masegaloeh's answer.
Then amavis send it back to the unix socket with smtp.

The problem was postfix. You have to create a unix socket which amavis can access without adding amavis to postmap or postfix group. So I first used `../amavis/amavis-accept` so the socket is successfully created. But postfix creates a pid file and it uses this name. As an unix socket postfix use `pid/unix. + services name` which was `pid/unix.../amavis/amavis-accept.`

So I created this link in the `public` folder and so postfix can create the socket (set permissions of the amavis directory) and I only need `amavis/amavis-accept` in the master.cf.

With this configuration, the pid file is `pid/unix.amavis/amavis.accept`. For that I only had to create the `unix.amavis directory` and because of `unix.amavis`and not `unix...amavis` it matches the style of the pid directory a bit.

***LMTP does not work for me!***

Comment: Great work! I've never thought that postfix and amavis can do two-ways communication over socket. But I curious why the protocol was different (SMTP &  LMTP)